# Simple Linq question: How to select more than one column?

Tags: sql, linq, select

my code is:

```
            List<Benutzer> users = (from a in dc.Benutzer
                                    select a).ToList();
```

I need this code but I only want to select 3 of the 20 Columns in the "Benutzer"-Table.
What is the syntax for that?

Comment: You have type `Benutzer`? Ever considered using localized C#? `Liste<Benutzer> benutzer = (aus a in dc.Benutzer wähle a).ZuListe();` ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's a query expression:

```
var users = (from a in dc.Benutzer
             select new { a.Name, a.Age, a.Occupation }).ToList();
```

Or in dot notation:

```
var users = dc.Benutzer.Select(a => new { a.Name, a.Age, a.Occupation })
                       .ToList();
```

Note that this returns a list of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) rather than instances of `Benutzer`. Personally I prefer this approach over creating a list of partially populated instances, as then anyone dealing with the partial instances needs to check whether they came from to find out what will really be there.

EDIT: If you really want to build instances of `Benutzer`, and LINQ isn't letting you do so in a query (I'm not sure why) you could always do:

```
List<Benutzer> users = dc.Benutzer
    .Select(a => new { a.Name, a.Age, a.Occupation })
    .AsEnumerable() // Forces the rest of the query to execute locally
    .Select(x => new Benutzer { Name = x.Name, Age = x.Age, 
                                Occupation = x.Occupation })
    .ToList();
```

i.e. use the anonymous type just as a DTO. Note that the returned `Benutzer` objects won't be associated with a context though.

Comment: What do you mean by "typisite"?

Comment: I want the type to be Benutzer, not anonymous.

Comment: You can if you provide Benutzer have parameterless constructor and public setters for desired properties. Or and constructor that fits the same purpose.

Answer (score 4):

```
    List<Benutzer> users = (from a in dc.Benutzer
                            select new Benutzer{
                             myCol= a.myCol,
                             myCol2 = a.myCol2
                             }).ToList();
```

I think that's what you want if you want to make the same kind of list. But that assumes that the properties you are setting have public setters.

Comment: You need a comma to seperate the fields, although i doubt that's why it's breaking

Comment: I just tried it on my machine with a very similar use case and it worked. Can you paste the exact error?

Comment: Explicit construction of entity type 'DAL.Benutzer' in query is not allowed.
Thats the error

Comment: Try removing the `Benutzer` from the query then: `select new { myCol = a.myCol, ... }` to construct an anonymous type.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you dont have a constructor which allows this. Make a constructor for your Benutzer class and do it the normal way. select new Benutzer(myCol, myCol2, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var list = (from a in dc.Benutzer select new {a.Col1, a.Col2, a.Col3}).ToList();
```

but now you have list of anonymous object not of Benutzer objects.